# Visual Studio 2015 C# Building in release .exe not running on some of other computers

Tags: c#

So I've looked everywhere and I can't find anything that fixes my problem...

I've had multiple people say my program doesn't run on there computers. I've questioned them about the .Net Framework they use, what windows they use, cpu, and everything that should make a difference.

Someone even installed a completely clean version of windows 10 just to try and use it, but it didn't open on it still.

It works fine on my computer but I can't find out why it isn't working on anyone else computer.

Here's the application direct download link(Dropbox): https://db.tt/7DieN69U

Edit:
I build the program in release.
I have the program signed.
The program has all the required libraries with it.

Edit 2:
None of the users are getting any errors, but no windows open, nothing opens for them, nothing shows for them either. They double click it. They even run it as admin. Nothing happens.

Edit 3:

Software specs:

.Net Framework 4 is the targeted framework

CPU is Any CPU

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for anybody to provide help here. Can you post the specific error your users are getting when the program fails to run?  You might find this in the event logs.

Comment: @innomatics there are no errors. It wont open at all for them, they say theres nothing popping up, nothing opens, no errors, no nothing.

Comment: You may want to look at how your application is handling errors in that case.  Make sure you aren't swallowing them and that they are being appropriately reported or logged.

Comment: @innomatics I'm sorry that I haven't given you enough information. I have given you every bit of information I have. I don't have a second computer to test this out on my own. You guys aren't being helpful at all. I've given you all the information I have and can get.

Comment: @innomatics I have quite a few handling errors in the application. Also Nothing happens before the application launches the main window. So there's nothing for me to figure out from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with innomatics look in the event log and see if there is an error in it for your application

It is also possible that the targeted .net framework is not installed or improperly installed on the target pc.

Comment: They even installed a fresh version of windows 10 which should automatically install a clean and nice version of the newest .Net Framework PROPERLY

Comment: just because it should work that way does not mean it will, check the event log and see if there are errors in it.

there is also

.NET Framework Setup Verification Utility and .NET Framework Cleanup Utility

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience, usual culprits are:

- Antivirus Software - make sure that your application's folder is listed as an exception on the host computer. Programs caught by your antivirus might fail silently.
- Libraries - Are your DLLs *ALL* copied locally? You may have dependencies that are installed on your computer, and they work because they are referenced correctly, however they are not actually built with the installer because they are taken from a source outside of your project. Check your DLLs one-by-one on your IDE and check on the installed DLLs on the client machine.